# Retorno de tabela MySQL com foreach PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Tenho a tabela de eventos e gostaria de retornar todas as linhas de uma consulta MySQL através do `foreach` no PHP, mas ele retorna apenas a primeira linha, podem me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```
<?php
include_once('evento/action/conexao.php');
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->conectar();

$data_selecionada = '2021-02-19';

$sql = "SELECT TIME(eventos.inicio) as ini, TIME(eventos.termino) as fim FROM eventos WHERE DATE(eventos.inicio) = '$data_selecionada' ORDER BY inicio";
$horarios = array();
$res = $db->prepare($sql);
$res->execute(); 
$dados = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($dados as $dado) {
    echo "</br>" . $dado;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função que você está utilizando `$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` só retorna a próxima linha da consulta, então para que você retorne todas as linhas da forma desejada você deveria criar um `while` chamando a função `$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` novamente à cada interação OU então utilizar a função `$res->fetchAll();` e aí utilizar o `foreach` na variável `$dados` recebendo a função correta.

Comment: muito obrigado, deu certo!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, a função ***fetch()*** do PDO retorna um elemento e coloca o ponteiro no próximo, se quiser todos, utilize o ***fecthAll()***:

```php
<?php
    include_once('evento/action/conexao.php');
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->conectar();

    $data_selecionada = '2021-02-19';

    $sql = "SELECT TIME(eventos.inicio) as ini, TIME(eventos.termino) as fim FROM 
       eventos WHERE DATE(eventos.inicio) = '$data_selecionada' ORDER BY inicio";
    $horarios = array();
    $res = $db->prepare($sql);
    $res->execute(); 
    //o erro está aqui... utilize fetchAll()
    //$dados = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dados = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($dados as $dado) {
        echo "</br>" . $dado;
    }
```

Comment: muito obrigado, deu certo!

Comment: Disponha, estamos aqui para isso. Se puder, aceite a resposta para marcar como resolvido. Até mais.